# Is there an accepted term for the opposite of mode in statistics?

Tags: statistics, terminology, descriptive-statistics

In descriptive statistics, there are terms for all sorts of things.  The mean, median, and mode for a set of data are each three very frequently thrown around examples.

The mode in particular is defined as the result that has occurred the most frequently.

Is there a name for the opposite of this?  Is there a name for the result which has occurred the *least* frequently (*but still a nonzero number of times*)?

If I were to guess at a name or come up with one myself, perhaps a name like "*anti-mode*" might be appropriate, but I was wondering if there was an already accepted name.

Comment: I think that's usually called an outlier :)

Comment: @Rahul not necessarily.  $(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3)$ I wouldn't call $2$ an outlier.

Comment: @Rahul For me an outlier is rather a data point that is really far from the others (quantitatively, people sometimes use 3 standard deviations as the critical distance). It's a different concept.

Comment: I feel like the mode itself is not a very broadly used statistic, but it does allow useful terminology such as "bimodal", etc. So I can't imagine a situation where the opposite of that would be particularly interesting to look at. Anti-mode sounds right as you suggest. Also, "loner"?

Comment: Apparently, antimode is used [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-58250-9_14) in that sense: between $m$ modes of an $m$-modal distribution, you can find $m-1$ antimodes.

Comment: For an unbounded distribution, this parameter does not exist. For a symmetric distribution, it can take two far-away values. For a bounded distribution, I guess that any estimator will be largely spread, as are rare events. I doubt that this is an interesting parameter.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: technically, an outlier is a sample that does not belong to the distribution under consideration (for instance, in a heads and tails game, could be a fake drawing added by a cheater). That doesn't mean that it is clearly discernible from the inliers.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Right. I was just speaking from a practical point of view as it's the only one I'm familiar with. But I still don't believe that it fits here, as in the example given $(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3)$ you wouldn't really be able to say that $2$ is so exceptional here that it can't be from the same population as the other numbers.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier: did I say the opposite ?

Comment: I don't think there is. Mode is easily generalizable to continuous case and it still make equal sense. It is difficult to generalize this concept to continuous case. Unless what you have is piecewise function (like uniform distribution), you can have value that is infinitesimally close to 0.

Comment: @YohanesAlfredo Well, apparently [antimode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution#Terminology) is precisely used in the continuous case to describe the least hit value in between two modes.

Comment: I am not necessarily refering to antimode. Please read what the asker asked "result which has occurred the least frequently (but still a nonzero number of times)". The antimode (although I just know the existence of such word) you mentioned is not the exact definition that the asker asked.

Comment: Proposal: analoguously to *"M O D E"* ( (m)ost (o)ften (d)etected (e)vent ) take *"L O D E"* for (l)east (o)ften (d)etected (e)vent ? (just kidding...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From *Communication Research Statistics* by John C. Reinard:

> Some have developed the notion of an **anti-mode** (Vogt, 2005, p. 11) to
>   describe the least frequent score, but thankfully, in communication
>   studies this term has not caught on.

I found indeed a number of sources where this terminology is used, including [the Wikipedia page on multimodal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multimodal_distribution#Terminology). However, as Reinard seems to be clearly saying, not everyone is fond of this terminology, so it wouldn't qualify as broadly accepted. Reinard doesn't suggest another word though, so I would still go for this one if I really needed a word.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the term

> least frequent score

which is from [@Armaud's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3446732/579255). That term is easily understood by anyone without needing to know any special definitions.

In the special case of a bimodal distribution, you could refer to the 'peaks' (the two modes) and 'trough' (the lowest point). Example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/504577/statistic-for-measuring-the-magnitude-of-bimodality-in-a-distribution#comment932464_504577):

> the extent of the difference between the peaks and trough of the (bimodal) distribution